# Macbook Pro A1261

Tags: macbook-pro, display

display, Macbook,

### REGARDING Macbook Pro 17" A1261 (black display)

Hi

I am using this computer for film editing using FCP7 which runs best w/ OSX10.6.8.

Recently I needed to wipe my SSD & re-install OSX 10.6.8 and FCP7 as FCP had developed a software conflict

During the re-installation the screen went "black" and I have been unable to fix it

The software re-installation the SSD was completed using another computer

The SSD runs perfectly as an external boot drive on other computers. When I replaced the screen I discovered that the old screen had been the problem; it still booted-up black.

When I boot this computer with the SSD or any other HDD, I hear the Apple Chime but the screen continues black (with some slight illumination + the APPLE Icon on the lid is illuminated too). The little light besides the latch comes on too. If I boot up in safe-mode (using the shift key) the keyboard light comes on also ( but not if I do not press the shift-key)

I have tried to boot it as the target w/ a firewire but the screen still comes on black

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Philip Hendel

Comment: Either your LCD or the GPU has failed.  Have you tried an external display?

Comment: Please try [this Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201257) and respond with results.